# Trouble parsing comments with praw

Tags: python, comments, counter, reddit, praw

I'm trying to scan a particular subreddit to see the how many times a comment appears in the top submissions.

I haven't been able to get any indication that it is actually reading the message, as it won't print the body of the message at all.
*Note:* 
sr = subreddit
phrase = phrase that's being looked for

I'm still new to praw and python (only picked it up in the last hour) but I've had a fair amount of experience in c.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    submissions = r.get_subreddit(sr).get_top(limit=1)
    for submission in submissions:
        comments = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(submission.replace_more_comments(limit=None, threshold=0))
        for comment in comments:
            print(comment.body.lower())
            if comment.id not in already_done:
                if phrase in comment.body.lower():
                    phrase_counter = phrase_counter + 1
```

Comment: Are you getting a `ConnectionError`?

Comment: I think `Submission.comments` is being buggy. It's returning empty lists for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Submission.replace_more_comments` return a list of the `MoreComment` objects that were *NOT* replaced. So if you're calling it with `limit=None` and `threshold=0` then it will return an empty list. See the [`replace_more_comments`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Submission.replace_more_comments) docstring. Here's a full example of how to use both `replace_more_comments` and `flatten_tree`. For more information see the [comment parsing](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/comment_parsing.html) page in our documentation.

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(UNIQUE_AND_DESCRIPTIVE_USERAGENT_CONTAINING_YOUR_REDDIT_USERNAME)
subreddit = r.get_subreddit('python')
submissions = subreddit.get_top(limit=1)
for submission in submissions:
    submission.replace_more_comments(limit=None, threshold=0)
    flat_comments = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(submission.comments)
    for comment in flat_comments:
        print(comment.body)
```